# NoClassDefFoundError when using FindBugs

Tags: java, android, findbugs

```
Error:Internal error: (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/jps/android/model/impl/JpsAndroidModuleProperties
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/jps/android/model/impl/JpsAndroidModuleProperties
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadModules(JpsProjectLoader.java:281)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadModules(JpsProjectLoader.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:100)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:266)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/jps/android/model/impl/JpsAndroidModuleProperties
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.model.impl.JpsAndroidModelSerializerExtension$1.loadExtension(JpsAndroidModelSerializerExtension.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.model.impl.JpsAndroidModelSerializerExtension$1.loadExtension(JpsAndroidModelSerializerExtension.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.facet.JpsFacetConfigurationSerializer.loadExtension(JpsFacetConfigurationSerializer.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.facet.JpsFacetSerializer.addExtension(JpsFacetSerializer.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.facet.JpsFacetSerializer.addFacets(JpsFacetSerializer.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.facet.JpsFacetSerializer.loadFacets(JpsFacetSerializer.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadModule(JpsProjectLoader.java:323)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.access$000(JpsProjectLoader.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader$2.call(JpsProjectLoader.java:276)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader$2.call(JpsProjectLoader.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.jps.android.model.impl.JpsAndroidModuleProperties
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following dependency to your Project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.adedayo.intellij.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-common</artifactId>
    <version>142.1</version>
</dependency>
```